# perl scrip to insert multiple line after a specific string

Tags: perl

I am trying to insert multiple line between a two specfic line in perl. But my code is having some issue which i am not able to figure it out.

```
open(FILE,"abc7.xml") || die "Can't open file: $!";
 undef $/;
 my $file = <FILE>;

 # Set strings to find and insert
 my $first_line = "<conf-front>";
 my $second_line = "<conf-proc-meta>";
 my $insert = "'<!--Delivery Date:11\/30\/2013-->\n<!--XML Script: 1111.22.3333-->\n<!--Batch:abcdef >'";

 # Insert our text
 $file =~ s/\Q$first_line\E\n\Q$second_line\E/$first_line\n$insert\n$second_line/;

 # Write output to output.txt
 open(OUTPUT,">output.txt") || die "Can't open file: $!";
 print OUTPUT $file;
 close(OUTPUT);
```

Comment: -1 for not describing which kind of issues.

Comment: issue is nothing but the content what i am trying to insert is not getting inserted

Comment: It is unlikely that you get any more help here as long as your refuse to give a more detailed problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Please explain better what is the problem you notice. The script itself does it's job just creates broken XML. That's because:

1) The $insert value has an additional set of quotes (the "'") that will break XML

2) The Batch line misses the closing tag "-->"

If you fix this two the resulting XML should be fine (if the rest of the original XML was fine).

Comment: I tried as above but no luck

Comment: Are you sure maybe your file doesn't have a "\r\n" as the end line (windows style)? In that case you should correct the match string.
(and yes I actually tried the code on a sample file ;) )